# Confuse about overloading global operator new in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

I am really cofused about overloading global `operator new` in c++,In this situation,i can understand it as `overload`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void *operator new( size_t n, const string &pat ) {
    char *p = static_cast<char *>(::operator new( n ));
    const char *pattern = pat.c_str();
    if( !pattern || !pattern[0] )
        pattern = "\0"; // note: two null chars
    const char *f = pattern;
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        if( !*f )
            f = pattern;
        p[i] = *f++;
    }
    cout<<"overload!"<<endl;
    return p;
}


int main() {
    string fill( "<garbage>" );
    string *string1 = new string( "Hello" ); // standard version
    string *string2 =
            new (fill) string( "World!" ); // overloaded version,why??? because fill will be the second parameter
                                            //and the parameter list is different from standard versions in new.h
    cout<<string1<<" "<<string2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In this codeblock,I write an overloaded version of `operator new`,it uses the standard version `::operator new()`,then I located thie location of the standard version:

```
//from new.h
void* operator new(std::size_t) _GLIBCXX_THROW (std::bad_alloc)
  __attribute__((__externally_visible__));
```

The only parameter's type in the standard version is `size_t`,then I "overload" this standard version:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//overload1
void *operator new( size_t n, const string &pat ) {
    char *p = static_cast<char *>(::operator new( n ));
    const char *pattern = pat.c_str();
    if( !pattern || !pattern[0] )
        pattern = "\0"; // note: two null chars
    const char *f = pattern;
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        if( !*f )
            f = pattern;
        p[i] = *f++;
    }
    cout<<"overload1"<<endl;
    return p;
}

//overload2
void* operator new(size_t n){//note:the same parameter as the standard version,why???
    cout<<"overload2"<<endl;
    return malloc(n);
}

int main() {
    string fill( "<garbage>" );
    string *string1 = new string( "Hello" ); // overloaded version:2
    string *string2 =
            new (fill) string( "World!" ); // overloaded version:2 and 1
    cout<<string1<<" "<<string2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This time,in my `overload1` version ,i called the `overload2` version  but not the standard version,but the parameter list of these two versions(`overload2` and `standard version`) are exactly the same!This is contrary to what I learned about overloading,I can understand this as replacement because in `new.h`,there is such a annotate:

> These are replaceable signatures: - normal single new and delete (no arguments, throw bad_alloc on error) - normal array new and delete (same) - nothrow single new and delete (take a nothrow argument, return NULL on error) - nothrow array new and delete (same) Placement new and delete signatures (take a memory address argument, does nothing) may not be replaced by a user's program.

So,Is the standard version replaced by my `overload2` version?Or it is just be overloaded(really confused me),should i stop claiming that such behavior as "overload"?But it seems like everyone calls it as "overload `operator new`"

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Would your confusion lessen if you called it [replacement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) instead of overload?

Comment: strictly speaking its not "normal" overloading. For overloading the signatures need to differ. Its a more colloquial use of the term "overloading".

Comment: Yes，it will@teapot418

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new